# I'm trying this scenario but it is not giving correct output

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

//*

WAP which takes deptno,dname as input and 
insert that records into dept table.

if deptno is already existing,then increment
its value by 10 and again try inserting.The 
insert is suposed to be tried 5 times and 
falling all 5 times, print amessage saying
'Try later'

*//

```
Alter procedure sp_update (
    @dno int,
    @dname varchar(30)
)
as begin
    declare @rowcount int
    set @rowcount=@@ROWCOUNT
    if @rowcount<5 
    begin
    if not exists (select dno from dept where @dno=dno)
    begin
    insert into dept (dno,dname) values (@dno,@dname)
    end
    else
    begin
    print 'Try later'
    end
    end
    else
    begin
    set @dno=(select max(dno) from dept)
    set @dno=@dno+10
    insert into dept (dno,dname) values (@dno,@dname)
    end
end



exec sp_update 10,'HR'
```

Please give the required output.

Comment: Some good formatting (indenting specifically) will make that SQL much easier to read, with all those `if`s

Answer (score 0):

The `@rowcount` variable at the begining of the procedure is always `<5`, it's never going to enter the segment where *"increment its value by 10 and again try inserting"*.

**EDIT:** In order to know how many times a user has executed the SP, you would have to insert into a log table, something like:

```
CREATE TABLE logSp (Username VARCHAR(200), ProcedureName VARCHAR(200), DateExecuted DATETIME)
```

And change the logic to this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_update (
    @dno int,
    @dname varchar(30)
)
AS 
BEGIN
  DECLARE @sp_name VARCHAR(200) = 'sp_update'
  DECLARE @maxtimes VARCHAR(200) = 5
  DECLARE @user VARCHAR(200) = SUSER_NAME()

  DECLARE @times INT
  SELECT @times = count(1)
  FROM logSp
  WHERE Username = @user
    AND ProcedureName = @sp_name

  IF @times = @maxtimes
  BEGIN
    PRINT 'Try Again'
    RETURN
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO logSp values (@user, @sp_name, GETDATE())
  END

  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT dno FROM dept WHERE @dno=dno)
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dept (dno,dname) VALUES (@dno,@dname)
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    SET @dno=(SELECT MAX(dno) FROM dept)
    SET @dno=@dno+10
    INSERT INTO dept (dno,dname) VALUES (@dno,@dname)
  END
END
```

Also, by setting the `@dno` variable to `max(id) + 10` you guarantee that 
the new deptno doesn't exist, yout don't have to try 5 times. If you want to try 5 times the INSERT you would have to use a `while`.

Comment: But this code is not restricting the  above 5 times,

Comment: if user will executes the sp more than 5 times it won't allow the insertion and display the message like 'Try later'

Comment: In that case, you would have to keep the record of how many times a user runs the SP (a log table for example). I've edited the answer including a log table to make that check.

Comment: off course this wll work fine but its not my requirement.